# Variations in the output of quantile regression models

Tags: r, regression, quantile-regression

I am trying to implement quantile regression models with R for the first time (I am new to this regression approach).

Here is the code that I am running:

```
library(quantreg)

qr_models = dataset %>%
group_by(lat) %>%
do(model = rq(julian_day~time, tau = 0.5, data= .))
```

As you can see, I have added a group_by condition, so the output gives as many models as I have groups. I use this to print the results:

```
qr_models$model %>%
purrr::map(broom::tidy)
```

My question is the following:

For some models, like model number 1, the output is like this:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  term        estimate std.error statistic       p.value   tau
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    65        2.86      22.7  0               0.5
2 time           -2.75     0.466     -5.91 0.00000000399   0.5
```

whereas for some others, like number 14, the output is like this:

```
[[14]]
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term        estimate conf.low conf.high   tau
  <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 (Intercept)    98       83.5      98      0.5
2 time            1.00     1.00      4.20   0.5
```

As you can see, the descriptors of my models are not the same (e.g. p-value, std.error, etc.): why?

My intuition is that it comes from the amount of data per category, so I tried this:

```
> c(table(dataset$lat))
  55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68 
2548 8061 5680 4838 9542 2850 1519 1461 6831 1459 4804  769  905  868
```

and I observed that the models with less data than the others have the output like number 14.

If this is indeed where the difference comes from, am I missing something in terms of the required amount of data for running a quantile regression? Is it not enough to estimate certain parameters? Should the data be (near-)equally distributed between each category for analysis?

Thank you very much for your help. Of course, if I need to add some precision, do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Why do you expect that the standard errors, p-values etc. have to be the same for all models (latitudes)? In any case, you've got it right yourself: the fewer observations, the higher the standard error in general.

Comment: are not the same as a category in the output, maybe it was badly written sorry. For number 1 I have: estimate/std.error/statistic/p.value/tau; whereas for number 14: estimate/conf.low/conf.high/tau.

Comment: You seem to be telling us the structure of the output of `rq` differs from one problem to the next.  The place to look for answers is its help page.

Comment: thank you, indeed I found that: "If se = NULL (the default) and covariance = FALSE, and the sample size is less than 1001, then the "rank" method is used, otherwise the "nid" method is used", so there was a threshold I did not know about.